# Issue with PLSQL Total field - not calculating

Tags: sql, select, plsql

I am trying to calculate 3 fields in a SELECT statement from CTE (within a View) in Oracle PLSQL. The issue is that the field is created however it's blank, i.e. not calculating.
The rest of the script is working fine. The only problem is the total field (called totalll).
Here is the full code. A picture of what the result look like is attached as well.
Wondering if there is any restriction in PLSQL as this a CTE within View.

```
create or replace view INVENTORY as
with
instock as
(select part_no, INV_PART_API.Get_Desc(contract,part_no) part_description, location_no, qty_onhand, qty_reserved,
(qty_onhand - qty_reserved) available_qty, objversion
from INVENTORY_PART_IN_STOCK
where location_no IN ('A','B','C', 'D') and qty_onhand > 0 ),
intransit as
(select part_no, 
shaw1app.INV_PART_API.Get_Desc(contract,part_no) part_description, 
location_no, 
qty_onhand On_Hand_In_Transit, 
qty_reserved Reserved_In_Transit,
(qty_onhand - qty_reserved) Available_Qty_In_Transit, objversion
from INVENTORY_PART_IN_STOCK
where location_no IN ('E') and qty_onhand > 0 ),
inprod as 
(select part_no, description, 
buy_qty_due Qty_in_Production, objversion from PUR_ORDER_LINE_ALL
where objstate in ('Confirmed', 'Released') and demand_code_db = 'Invent Order' and
vendor_no = '11111'),
quarantine as
(select part_no, INV_PART_API.Get_Desc(contract,part_no), location_no, qty_onhand OnHandQuar, qty_reserved ReservedQuarantine,
(qty_onhand - qty_reserved) Available_Qty_Quar

from INVENTORY_PART_IN_STOCK
where location_no IN ('N-QA', 'N8-QA') and qty_onhand > 0)


select s.part_no, s.part_description, s.location_no, s.qty_onhand, s.qty_reserved,s.available_qty,
t.On_Hand_In_Transit,
t.Reserved_In_Transit,
t.Available_Qty_In_Transit,
q.OnHandQuar, q.ReservedQuarantine, q.Available_Qty_Quar,
p.Qty_in_Production, (s.available_qty + t.Available_Qty_In_Transit + p.Qty_in_Production ) totalll
from
instock s
left join intransit t on t.part_no = s.part_no
left join inprod p on p.part_no = s.part_no
left join quarantine q on q.part_no = s.part_no

with read only;
```

[image]

Let me know if I need to explain further.

Thank you!

Comment: Please add your database. Please add the example data and expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any restriction to addition or there should be.

But what I see from code provided is you are doing a sum of 3 fields to get the `totalll` as

```
(s.available_qty + t.available_qty_in_transit + p.qty_in_production) totalll
```

and with the example output you provided there is value available only in `s.available_qty` where as other fields `t.available_qty_in_transit` and `p.qty_in_productionare` are null which leads to the final result also to null. any arithmetic operation involving null will be final result null.

change it to ,

```
(nvl(s.available_qty,0) + nvl(t.available_qty_in_transit,0) + nvl(p.qty_in_production,0)) totalll
```

should solve the issue.